# How to multiply with lists in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to Python and I want to store the float value in a list, then use the value in the list to work with until i reset it back to empty. I'm getting this error thrown:

```
python TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'list' >>>
```

The program is a basic distance, speed and time calculator, I haven't added anything like the units yet but I've hit this hurdle. How can I multiply correctly in the `equate()` function?

```
import math
import random
import os

distance = []
speed = []
time = []
result = []

def di():
    while True:
        try:
            di = float(input('Enter Distance:> '))
            distance.append(di)
            print('You entered', distance)
            sp()
        except ValueError:
            print('Thats not a number')
            pass

def sp():
    while True:
        try:
            sp = float(input('Enter Speed:> '))
            speed.append(sp)
            print('You have entered', speed)
            ti()
        except ValueError:
            print('Thats not a number')
            pass

def ti():
    while True:
        try:
            ti = float(input('Enter Time:> '))
            time.append(ti)
            print('You have entered', time)
            equate()
        except ValueError:
            print('Thats not a number')
            pass

def equate():
    print('What do you want to calculate?')
    option = input('1.Distance, \n2.Speed, \n3.Time, \n4.Exit Program, \n:>')
    if option == '1':
        res = speed * time
        result.append(res)
        print(result)
    elif option == '2':
        res = distance / time
        result.append(res)
        print(result)
    elif option == '3':
        res = distance / speed
        result.append(res)
        print(result)
    elif option == '4':
        sys.exit('Goodbye')
    else:
        print('Thats not an option')
        pass

def running():
    input('Distance Speed and Time Caluclator \nPress any key to enter the values')
    di()

running()
```

EDIT: FULL ERROR

Python 3.4.4 (v3.4.4:737efcadf5a6, Dec 20 2015, 20:20:57) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.

> > > 

```
===================== RESTART: C:\Python34\equations.py =====================
Distance Speed and Time Caluclator 
Press any key to enter the values
Enter Distance:> 30
You entered [30.0]
Enter Speed:> 20
You have entered [20.0]
Enter Time:> 10
You have entered [10.0]
What do you want to calculate?
1.Distance, 
2.Speed, 
3.Time, 
4.Exit Program, 
:>1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\equations.py", line 69, in <module>
    running()
  File "C:\Python34\equations.py", line 67, in running
    di()
  File "C:\Python34\equations.py", line 16, in di
    sp()
  File "C:\Python34\equations.py", line 27, in sp
    ti()
  File "C:\Python34\equations.py", line 38, in ti
    equate()
  File "C:\Python34\equations.py", line 47, in equate
    res = speed * time
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'list'
```

Comment: Please include the full error in your question.

Comment: `speed` and `time` are both lists, and you are multiplying them. You cannot do that.

Comment: POST EDITED WITH ERROR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error seems to be occurring when you are multiplying in the `equate` function. I think you are trying to multiply a list by a list, as @TigerhawkT3 says. Instead, I recommend using `speed[-1]`, `time[-1]` and `distance[-1]` (to get the last item, as that is what the user just put in) whenever you reference them in your `equate()` function. Eg, for multiply:

```
if option == '1':
    res = speed[-1] * time[-1]
    result.append(res)
    print(result)
```

*Edit: Thanks for making the question more concise*

Comment: This worked perfectly, does what I need it too, thanks very much! I appreciate the quick resolve

Answer (score 0):

First of all you don't need `while` loop on each function, one time would be enough.
Second, you want to calculate values for each item in list. In yours case, option example:

```
if option == '1':
        #it would be nice to check if arrays are the same size etc.
        for i in range(len(time)):
            result.append(speed[i] * time[i])

        print(result)
```

Keep in mind that result is an arrray.

Comment: That seems a good way to do it. Could you explain the len aspect of it? does that mean it will select each number stored in the list and use that? or would it locate a specific part of the list? sorry to sound like such a noob this is quite new to me

Comment: `for i in range(len(time))` is a rather... non-Pythonic approach and generally discouraged. `for spd, tm in zip(speed, time)` might be better. Also the result is a list. :-)

Comment: I use len(time) only for getting the length of array ;). So in my case len(time) = number of items in integer. And in this loop it is just an index, and it goes from 0 to len(time) with step 1, like 0,1,2,...,max. Then in loop i am getting each item by index with brackets: array[i] returns item with index, example time[0], get first element.